# bash gunzip | untar multiple files in separated folders

Tags: bash, tar

I have a list of .tar.gz files with the same inner folder structure and I'd like to batch gunzip | untar a single file from them in separated folders.

logs_2013-08-01.tar.gz
logs_2013-08-02.tar.gz
logs_2013-08-03.tar.gz
logs_2013-08-04.tar.gz
logs_2013-08-05.tar.gz

I know the command to untar a single file is

```
tar -xvf {tarball.tar} {path/to/file}
```

And adding the -C to specify the output folder the command for a single archive looks like:

```
tar -xvf logs_2013-08-01.tar.gz -C 2013-08-01/ /var/logs/audit
```

But how can I do a loop to untar everything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this (tested on Linux/bash):

```
for pkg in logs_*.tar.gz; do
   where="${pkg#logs_}"
   where="${where%.tar.gz}/"

   [ -d "$where" ] || mkdir "$where"

   tar zxfv $pkg -C "$where" /var/logs/audit
done
```

Simply, you loop over all the tgz archives in the current dircetory, then you take "date" part from its name, create required directory and extract them finally.

Comment: Just the solution I was asking for.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`atool(1)`](http://www.nongnu.org/atool/). It is already packaged for many distributions.

Just run:

```
$ atool -x -e *.tar.gz
```

to uncompress and untar every file in its own directory.

Comment: I'd like to avoid uncompressing everything due to lack of disk space in the server.

Comment: Take a look at `atool`'s manpage, you can extract a single file too.

Comment: This was much easier than the above script. But installing atool is one additional step, but that's useful for future purposes as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply loop over the files like this

```
#!/bin/bash
# Pass the name of the file to unpack on the command line $1
for file in *.gz
do
    dir=$(echo "$file" | cut -c 6-15)
    tar -xvf "$file" -C "$dir" "$1"
done
```